# at what point in the MVC WebAPI lifecycle does "MS_HttpContext" get set?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

We have a Web API 5.0.0.0 app and we have the following code:

```
public class LoggingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var context = request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"] as HttpContextBase;

        // Throws null reference exception in some environments
        var headers = context.Response.Headers;

        ... some more random code ...
    }
}
```

This works in most of our environments, but in one particular environment the **context** variable is always null.

It seems to me that there is a race condition, and that in some environments **request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]** is being set before this handler method is invoked, and in other environments it is not yet set.

Can anyone explain the lifecycle events regarding when the **MS_HttpContext** request property is set versus when the DelegatingHandler's **SendAsync** method is invoked?

Comment: How are you sending request to inner handlers? is there any code between the two lines you have shown? context and headers?